# Completely disable redirection for Guzzle

Tags: javascript, php, redirect, guzzle, guzzle6

`Guzzle6` has one pretty option: `allow_redirects`. If setting this option to `false` value, Guzzle blocking redirect if response code like `302` or `Headers` has `Location` param.

But there is one problem. If redirect sends by client – Guzzle doesn't notice this. For example:

We have some URL `http://example.com/` that redirected to page `http://redirected.com/`. Send request with help Guzzle:

```
$oClient->request('POST', 'http://redirected.com/', [
    'form_params' => $aFormData,
    'cookies' => (new CookieJar($aPrepareCookie)),
    'debug' => true,
    'allow_redirects' => false
]);
```

Suppose that `redirect.com` has `index.php` like this:

```
<?php
    header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
?>
```

In this case, the redirection will be blocked from Guzzle.

Now, let's see this redirect example:

```
<?php
    echo '<script>window.location = "http://www.example.com/";</script>';
?>
```

Here we have a problem because this is client side redirect and his can't affect the `Headers`, Therefore `Guzzle` can't track HTTP Status Code or Location value.

So, how i can solve this problem and find solution?

Thanks for help!

Comment: guzzle doesn't execute javascript, it just performs the HTTP request - your problem has to be solved downstream since it resides in what you're doing with the request content.

Comment: @Calimero you offer to get a page on which there is the window.location and cut this, for example. But, a can't get page because immediately executed redirect.

Comment: I suspect you're performing a request with guzzle in a webpage and sending back the request's content to the client - only a web browser will execute a JS redirect. Guzzle being only an HTTP client, it's out of its responsibilities to handle this for you. but you easily can filter the response content if needed.

Answer (score 1):

As previous posters have said, Guzzle will not execute the javascript.

Your problem could easily be solved by utilizing [Guzzle Middleware](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/handlers-and-middleware.html#middleware).

Within the middleware:

- receive the response
- parse the body for window.location="someurl"
- perform a request of "someurl"
- modify the header of the response from "someurl" to include the fact that it was a redirection.
- return the response.